# Admob mediation got request but no impressions from other ad services

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I add Mediation on MyApps published and i followed all google guide to do that.
I create a profile on Facebook Developers, create a Banner and add the information on AdMob for mediation.
Included the Facebook SDK on Module:app gradle and the situation is that i see Banner from Admob only.

Facebook audience get request as i can see from AdMob but not Impressions!
If i understand with mediation i don't need to change the code of my AdMob banner just include the SDK?

Same situation for MoPub...i got request but no impressions...

With Facebook i try to set ecmp very low to AdmoB network for see the facebook banner but nothing...still show the Admob banner.

Here the gradle, maybe i'm wrong in sdk inclusion?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 25
        versionName "3.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Pubblicità google
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Pubblicità Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.1'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.27.1.0'
}
```

AdMob image
[image]

**EDIT**

For example for Facebook by Admob mediation i need the Banner code for Facebook? like that [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-banners) or via mediation i can see Facebook banner into Admob banner?
I still don't getting impressions but only request.

**EDIT 2**

Still increase request from MoPub and Facebook Networks but no impressions.
I Update all the SDK into application...i read all two integration guide from Facebook and from AdMob and nothing happends!

Answer (score 0):

Submit for review after approval you will see the impressions.